# Not able to INSERT more than 1K records to temp table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL, please help me.

I am trying insert more than 1k records to SQL temp table, I am getting this error:

> The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values

Please help me how to solve insert records into the temp table. I need to insert 5k records, kindly help me

This is my script

```
use DatabaseName
SET NOCOUNT ON
Create Table TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber) 
VALUES 
(1),
(2),
(3)
.
.
.
.
(999),
(1000),
(1001),
(1002)
.
.
```

Comment: Where did those 1K values come from? Why not *import* the data using BCP or `BULK INSERT`? It's highly unusual to use a script to insert more than a few dozen rows of data. The bulk commands minimal logging too, resulting in far better performance than a simple INSERT

Comment: Did you try to copy a database by creating a script (dump) instead of of a backup perhaps? That's only needed in database products without (free) real backups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on where your actual values for your insert are coming from could change what/how to do the INSERT part.  Are you doing the insert from a single connection or opening and closing a connection to use the data?  This would change how you could do it as well.

You are using a table variable (the @ in front of name shows that).  See my notes and code below for what is wrong and how to fix it.

```
use DatabaseName 

SET NOCOUNT ON 

-- this is creating  permeant table not a temp table or table variable.
CREATE Table TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10))

-- this inserts into a table variable not temp table
INSERT INTO @TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber)



-- this will create a temp table
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempRefundDetails') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #TempRefundDetails

CREATE TABLE #TempRefundDetails ( 
    PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #TempRefundDetails (
    PolicyNumber
)
VALUES (), () -- and so on

OR select from another table source directly into the table

INSERT INTO #TempRefundDetails (
    PolicyNumber
)
Select PolicyNumber
From SomeTableNameHere
```

Comment: Thnak you for the response, I am still getting same error - Msg 10738, Level 15, State 1, Line 1017
The number of row value expressions in the INSERT statement exceeds the maximum allowed number of 1000 row values.

Comment: The issue is too many VALUE statements like @aaron posted above:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65799351/1459036  So may need combination of his and this to use a temp table vs table variable  (table variables are not good for large data sets)

Comment: So depending on what/how you are getting the values in your VALUE statement, you would change the code but would need to know where/how you are getting them to provide better answer.  Im guessing the data above is not the actual data because if you just wanted numbers 1-5000 there are way better ways to do that.

Answer (score 6):

You can only do a max of 1'000 with a single `VALUES()` construct - if you need more, you need to repeat the `INSERT` statment:

```
INSERT INTO @TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber) 
VALUES (1), ....., (1000);

INSERT INTO @TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber) 
VALUES (1001), ....., (2000);

INSERT INTO @TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber) 
VALUES (2001), ....., (3000);
```

and so forth

Comment: Exactly. Here the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#limitations-and-restrictions

Comment: Or use BCP/BULK INSERT to load the data from a file instead of scripting it. Although I wonder where did those 1K rows come from? Was this another attempt to use a dump instead of a real backup?

Answer (score 3):

[The documentation is explicit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) about this limitation, and suggests multiple workarounds:

> When used as the VALUES clause of an INSERT ... VALUES statement, there is a limit of 1000 rows. Error 10738 is returned if the number of rows exceeds the maximum. To insert more than 1000 rows, use one of the following methods:
>
> - Create multiple INSERT statements
> - Use a derived table
> - Bulk import the data by using the bcp utility, the .NET SqlBulkCopy class, OPENROWSET (BULK ...), or the BULK INSERT statement

Comment: If availalbe to you you can utilize SSIS packages as well.  Basics here:  https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-ssis/

Answer (score -2):

The purpose of the code is not clear, but you can insert records using the WHILE LOOP

```
DECLARE @TempRefundDetails TABLE (PolicyNumber NVARCHAR(10))

DECLARE @cnt INT = 1;

WHILE @cnt < 5001 <-- your number here
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @TempRefundDetails (PolicyNumber) VALUES (@cnt)
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @TempRefundDetails
```